# Можно ли упростить код:? Пытался через цикл, но не получалось

Tags: python-3.x

задачка про монетку

```
import random
a = ["O", "P"]
s = ""
s2 = ""
s3 = ""
s4 = ""
s5 = ""
s6 = ""
s7 = ""
s8 = ""
s9 = ""
s10 = ""
while ("PPP" not in s) and ("OOO" not in s):
        s += random.choice(a)
print(s, "(попыток:"+str(len(s))+")")
while ("PPP" not in s2) and ("OOO" not in s2):
        s2 += random.choice(a)
print(s2, "(попыток:"+str(len(s2))+")")
while ("PPP" not in s3) and ("OOO" not in s3):
        s3 += random.choice(a)
print(s3, "(попыток:"+str(len(s3))+")")
while ("PPP" not in s4) and ("OOO" not in s4):
        s4 += random.choice(a)
print(s4, "(попыток:"+str(len(s4))+")")
while ("PPP" not in s5) and ("OOO" not in s5):
        s5 += random.choice(a)
print(s5, "(попыток:"+str(len(s5))+")")
while ("PPP" not in s6) and ("OOO" not in s6):
        s6 += random.choice(a)
print(s6, "(попыток:"+str(len(s6))+")")
while ("PPP" not in s7) and ("OOO" not in s7):
        s7 += random.choice(a)
print(s7, "(попыток:"+str(len(s7))+")")
while ("PPP" not in s8) and ("OOO" not in s8):
        s8 += random.choice(a)
print(s8, "(попыток:"+str(len(s8))+")")
while ("PPP" not in s9) and ("OOO" not in s9):
        s9 += random.choice(a)
print(s9, "(попыток:"+str(len(s9))+")")
while ("PPP" not in s10) and ("OOO" not in s10):
        s10 += random.choice(a)
print(s10, "(попыток:"+str(len(s10))+")")
b = [len(s), len(s2), len(s3), len(s4), len(s5),\
          len(s6), len(s7), len(s8), len(s9), len(s10)]
print("Минимальное количество попыток:", min(b))
print("Среднее количество попыток:", sum(b)/len(b))
print("Максимальное количество попыток:", max(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
s_all = []
b=[]
def f(index):
    global s_all
    while ("PPP" not in s_all[index]) and ("OOO" not in s_all[index]):
        s_all[index]+=random.choice(a)
    print(s_all[index], "(попыток:"+str(len(s_all[index]))+")")

for i in range(0, 10):
    s_all.append('')
    f(i)

for i in s_all:
    b.append(len(i))

print("Минимальное количество попыток:", min(b))
print("Среднее количество попыток:", sum(b)/len(b))
print("Максимальное количество попыток:", max(b))
```